# Hosting two logically separate apps on one node.js server?

Tags: node.js

Currently I have two apps each with their own node.js server, that means there is a lot of duplication, the node_modules are similar, the configuration is similar.

One app is served on the main domain, and the other is served on a sub domain.

The biggest thing is the sessions are separate, so I can't log into one and be logged into both.

How do I create one server to work for app.example.com and example.com so that they share common node_modules and configuration, but I can tailor specific needs for each app in that server?

Comment: Have a common modules directory and use a symlink to it in both app's directories, and use Redis or similar to share sessions across both apps.

Comment: So redis is they key to sharing sessions between both apps.

Comment: Not the only solution, but I think it's the best as it's extremely fast (because everything happens in memory). If you need something more persistent you may use MySQL.

Comment: I have always avoided redis because I cant wrap my head around it, I figured I would just merge the two apps and create one git repo that way maintaining would be easier. Where does redis live, on one of my apps or do I need to create a third server specifically for redis. Do you have any links to tutorials for this specific case?

Comment: It's a totally separate server process (it can live on a separate machine if you want), and your two Node apps just connect to it over TCP.

Comment: More info : http://redis.io/ and https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

Comment: If you don't need two separate processes, you can integrate your two apps with one common shell and then give each app its own Express Router (so each can add logic to the routes it wants to serve).  See [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/learn-to-use-the-new-router-in-expressjs-4) if you want to read about how Routers work in Express.

Comment: Yup that's what I plan on doing jfriend00. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [Nginx](http://nginx.com/), it will allow you to `proxy_pass` both subdomains to different ports. Here's the sort of setup you will need.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  app.example.com;
    access_log off;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I use nginx and do proxy my node servers. I didn't think to point both dns servers to one node app, I think thats what you're getting at. I think I am just going to merge the apps into one, but I would like to serve to second app on a subdomain so nginx may help me with that!